# How to order multiple managed servers under a domain in ansible inventory yaml format

Tags: ansible, ini, ansible-inventory

I need to update a yaml inventory with multiple managed servers and apply different variables to each of them. The current yaml structure has only one admin server per domain.

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
  children:
    targets:
      hosts:
        Domain1:
          ansible_host: "www.example1.com"
          admin_url: "t3://www.example1.com"
        Domain2:
          ansible_host: "www.example2.com"
          admin_url: "t3://www.example2.com"
```

so the ansible_host under domain 1 and 2 are admin servers. Now i will like to add multiple managed servers under each domain and still have the flexibility to assign each server (both admin and managed) different variable values if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a deep look at the [yaml inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html) to understand how they are structured. IMHO they are a little more complex to understand for starters than the historic ini inventories. You should have a good understanding of [all the inventory concepts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) before starting anyway

How you should read your current inventory file:

The generic group `all` declares:

- one direct child host named `localhost`
- one children group named `targets` with two hosts named `Domain1` and `Domain2`

From your question, I understand that you would like to treat Domain1 and Domain2 as groups (as their names suggests), not as hosts.

You probably have to rewrite your inventory like the following.

```
all:
  children:
    targets:
      vars:
        admin_url: "t3://{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      children:
        Domain1:
          hosts:
            www.example1.com:
            www.example2.com:
            www.yetanother.com:
        Domain2:
          hosts:
            host1.domain2.com:
            host2.domain2.com:
            host3.domain2.com:
```

Things to notice:

- I dropped the reference to localhost. It is always available by default.
- I kept your top level group `targets`. Since all admin addresses have the same format, I declared a var for that group which will be used for every host using its `inventory_hostname` (see [ansible magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables))
- Your `targets` group now has two children groups: `Domain1` and `Domain2` both declaring their hosts.
- Since we now declare hosts with their real names, there is no need to set ansible_host to a different value, so no hosts vars are needed so far.

Hope this will help you getting started.